# Traveling from Warsaw to Kaliningrad

Tags: car-rentals, transportation, warsaw, kaliningrad

What are the options for traveling from Warsaw to Kaliningrad?

Is there a car rental company that allows crossing from Poland to Kaliningrad?

In case I travel by car to the Poland side of the border, is there decent transportation from the border to Kaliningrad?

Answer (score 2):

Available options:

- Direct flights
- Duirect buses
- Private taxi transfer
- connection in Gdansk or Elblag

Check this article for details: http://kaliningradguide.com/2018/02/02/warsaw-kaliningrad-tickets/

I don't know about any successful story about crossing the border using a car rented in Poland.